# How can I handle ClarisWorks documents on Lion?

Tags: macos

I've a lot of ancient ClarisWorks documents and I want to upgrade to OS X Lion. Is there a way to have a look at or to print ClarisWorks document on Lion?

Comment: Do you own Pages? It will open ClarisWorks text documents. Numbers will open Clarisworks spreadsheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From one of the [Apple Discussion forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3510797?start=0&tstart=0), one user found a tool that could handle batch conversions of Claris Works documents:

> Panergy Software had just the right tool for me. It's called **Doc X
>   Converter**. I haven't used it yet, but I emailed with their tech
>   support and I understand that it will **batch convert Apple Works and
>   Claris Works files to .rtf files**, which, of course, will open fine
>   with any version of Word. (They no longer sell One Click Convert.)
>   **However, it'll only convert the word processor files.**

The [Panergy product page](http://www.panergy-software.com/products/docxconverter/index.html) has a link to a [FAQ](http://www.panergy-software.com/support/docXConverterFAQ.html), which states:

> The cwk file extension is the extension associated with an Office
>   program originally called ClarisWorks and later renamed AppleWorks.
>   This Office program is composed of several modules, word processor,
>   spreadsheet, drawing, painting, presentation and database. The cwk
>   extension is used for all the files regardless of the module that has
>   created them and is also used in both version 5 or version 6 of this
>   program. **docXConverter open and converts the cwk word processing
>   files of version 5 or version 6.**

So long as the ClarisWorks documents are version 5 or 6 and are word processing documents, this tool should provide the functionality that you're looking for.

**Caveat**: I've never used docXConverter before, but the product description looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

I recently recovered some ClarisWorks 3.0 documents using a 68k emulator. I wrote up my experiences here: http://www.danvk.org/wp/2012-05-21/reading-clarisworks-3-documents-in-mac-os-x/

Emulation may not be the most direct way to do this, but it's certainly the most fun!